# Microservices inter communication with multiple Microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

New to Microservices, trying to get hands-on it, I know it's going to be a big one but please bear with me. So can anyone please guide me on the best approach on,

- How to interact / communicate with multiple Microservice (5 in my case) from a service class method of 
  another Microservice.
- What if one of those Microservices is down, how to handle?
- How does Transaction Management work in this case?
- and finally, how to combine all those responses and send back as a single `ResponseEntity<APIResponse>`

Thank You for reaching this for with reading, please guide me on this.

Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

It's a very big question. The answers can write more than one book. I'll try to list something in my idea for you to get a piece of this.

- Communication between microservices.

  - Sync ways. Through HTTP requests,  RPC methods, or SOAP.
  - Async ways. Event sourcing, such as Kafka, RabbitMQ. Database sharing.
- **What if one of those Microservices is down, how to handle?**

  - This is how you handle your availability,  most of the time all microservices will have more than one instance.
  - Based on multiple instances, you could implement some strategies to help you control disasters,  such as Circuit Breaker, Retry, Throttling.
- **How does Transaction Management work in this case?**

  - You can try distributed transaction framework,  but they often seem to be too complicated.
  - The most common practice in design distributed systems, is CAP and Eventually Consistency. check wiki
- **how to combine all those responses and send back as a single**

  - This actually depends on how you design your API, you can always use API Gateway methods,  handle all your logic to FE in one service.

Above is very little about the question,  you could read some book or google detail solution online.

Comment: `Event sourcing` is not about "communication" but "data persistence". A better name would be "Event Notifications"

Comment: what do you mean by "distributed transaction framework"

Comment: What I mean about event sourcing, is actually EDA,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture.

Comment: Distributed Transaction is supported by some distributed database, such as OceanBase，TiDB. Distributed Transaction framework is more like middleware between your database and services, such as https://github.com/seata/seata

Comment: OK but event sourcing is not about "communication between microservices". Regarding distributed transactions you should avoid algorith consensus like 2PC and  prefer handle a "business" transaction with multiple "local" transactions(one local by microservice). Look at saga pattern , it is modelise as multiple local transactions and "compensating" transactions to handle rollback.